# Which variables are free in $\forall x (\exists y (x < y+z) \to \exists z (x < y+z))$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

anyone could explain for me, why $x,y,z$ is bound variable in this formula?

$ \forall x [ \exists y (x < y+z) \to \exists z (x < y+z) ] $

I think $y,z$ is free variable.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @GitGud, this is my instructor note, but I couldn't understand why?

Comment: What can't you understand? You are correct, $y$ and $z$ are free.

Comment: why y,z is free and x is bounded? sorry for my simple question. ! please answer to it :) thanks from your kindly note for my simple question. @GitGud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

We can use the *recursive* definition of the set $FV(\varphi)$ of *free* variables of a formula $\varphi$.

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA59) (5th ed - 2013), page 59 :

> **Definition** The set $FV(\varphi)$ of *free* variables of $\varphi$ is defined by
>
> > *(i)* if $\varphi$ is an atomic formula $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, then $FV(\varphi)= \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$;
> >
> > *(ii)* if $\varphi$ is an atomic formula $x_1 = x_2$, then $FV(\varphi)= \{ x_1, x_2 \}$;
> >
> > *(iii)* $FV(\varphi \to \psi) = FV(\varphi) \cup FV(\psi)$;
> >
> > *(iv)* $FV(¬ \varphi) = FV(\varphi)$;
> >
> > *(v)* $FV(∀x_i \varphi) = FV(∃x_i \varphi) = FV(\varphi) − \{ x_i \}$.

We can apply the above definition to "compute" $FV$ for your formula :

- $FV(x<y+z) = \{ x,y,z \}$
- $FV(∃y(x<y+z)) = \{ x,y,z \} - \{ y \} = \{ x,z \}$

In the same way :

- $FV(∃z(x<y+z)) = \{ x,y \}$

and thus :

- $FV(∃y(x<y+z)→∃z(x<y+z))= \{ x,z \} \cup \{ x,y \} = \{ x,y,z \}$.

Finally :

> $$FV(∀x[∃y(x<y+z)→∃z(x<y+z)]) = $$
>
> $$= \{ x,y,z \} - \{ x \} = \{ y,z \}.$$

Answer (score 4):

the same var may have both free and bound occurrences in the same formula.

A quantifier bounds the var that follows it, within the scope of that quantifier.

So, $x$ is bound by the starting $\forall x$, in the entire formula.

The first and second occurrence of $y$ (before the $\to$ sign) are bound.
The last occurrence of $y$ is free (it is not within the scope of $\exists y)$.

The first occurrence of $z$ is free, the second and the third are bound by the 
$\exists z$.

Comment: You could fix it up as follows: 

$ \forall x [ \exists y  \exists z[(x < y+z) \to (x < y+z)] ] $ 

Although it still wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @Dan I don't understand what you mean by fixing it, the question does not ask about fixing it, or about the intended meaning of the formula. As far as I am concerned the question is purely syntactical and the formula need not have any meaning, and need not fixing.

Comment: I am just illustrating what a similar though syntactically correct statement might look like. I did not mean to suggest they were logically equivalent. Good point.

Comment: @Dan now I understand why you included the remark "still wouldn't make much sense", so you were not concerned about the meaning of the formula either, just wanted to come up with a sample sentence (i.e. no free variables in the formula).

Comment: so, if we say y  and z  are free and x is bound is false?

Comment: it is the truth, but not the whole truth.

Comment: oh ! if you want to say which one is bounded and which one is free? ???? can you say?

Comment: if one variable 1 times be free and 1 times be bound ---> it's free?

Comment: is is possible to answer to my question ?

Comment: I did answer your question. The question is not just whether x is bound or free, but which occurrence of x is bound and which occurrence is free. If it is 1 times bound and 1 times free, then it is bound and it is free. If you insist on only one "answer" then I would suggest that it is bound.